# Loading image from the server using resource folder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am loading my images from **resource** folder. Now the requirement have change and I have to develop the WebGL Player instaed of standalone build.
Now my question is do resource exist on server and will it work on the server same or i need to change everywhere with **www and co-routine** like below.

```
public string url = "http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg";

void OnGUI() { 
   if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10,10,300,10),"click to load from server")){
       StartCoroutine("LoadImageFromServer");
    }
}//*/

IEnumerator LoadImageFromServer() {
    WWW www = new WWW(url);

    // Wait for download to complete
    yield return www;
    Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
}
```

Comment: If you include your images in your unity project than they will be downloaded together with the source and cached locally. But anyways, even if the protocl is "http://" or "file://" it should work all the same.

Comment: I think you can load image from server using resource folder after accepting  answers from your 3 previous questions. Otherwise anyone who tries to help is wasting their time!

Comment: Mostly, you should think about whether you want the build to be huge and lose potential player because of endless downloading on start or you want a tiny build and download only required assets for specific scenes. Then you would place it all on the server and make WWW requests for the asset (whether raw assets or AssetBundle).